# retrieve parentNode of text with regex Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a RegEX :

```
var re = RegExp("(?:^\\W*|(" + motBefore.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&") + ")\\W+)" + motErreur.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\W+(" + motAfter.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&") + ")|\\W*$)", "g");
```

With this RegEX I can find in my page the place of a certain word regarding is positionning (like this I don't have multiple occurence if it is not the one I want).

I would like to suround the motErreur with a span. The fact is I can't do this with a simple replace and altering the innerHTML because it mess up the tags of my page.

I am using :

```
var result = document.getElementById('edth_corps');
var textRangeGlobal = document.body.createTextRange();
textRangeGlobal.moveToElementText(result);
if(textRangeGlobal.findText(motErreur)){
    var html= "<span id='"+nbId+"' class='erreurOrthographe' oncontextmenu='rightClickMustWork(event, this);return false'>" + motErreur + "</span>";
    textRangeGlobal.pasteHTML(html);
}
```

What I would like it that `var result` don't be `document.getElementById('edth_corps');` but the Node where I got the result with my RegEX.

I am on IE5 and can't figure out how to get the Node using the RegEx (I tried with `match` but it did not work.

Anybody have an Idea how to do so ?

Comment: Did you say IE5? So you're using Win95?

Comment: @torazaburo quirck mode compatibility :(

Comment: "i" before "e" except after "c"

Comment: Spellcheck your question title.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex is not a good approach to this problem. You would be better off creating a dom element and using the dom traversal to remove the unwanted elements. You can do this code similar to the:

```
var wrap = document.createElement('div');
wrap.innerHTML = "your html";
```

Now you can work with the "virtual "element using dom selectors.
and the append the node to the dom

```
target.appendChild(wrap.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
```

Comment: Query selectors do not exist in IE5.... this is why I posted a question here and use RegEx. If the Query selectors was there I could already have the solution by myself for this.

Comment: ) i fix typo, change to "dom selectors"

Comment: there is still a big issue, the RegEx need to be use so in the sentence :
"this test that, but not test this". the first test will be inside the created SPAN but the seconde not, this is where the RegEx is used, so we can prévent duplicate from having the same thing going when we don't want to. Plus your answer is just partial so it does not fully answer to the question.